# Can you make a player start on a boat in the map editor?

Tags: far-cry-4

In Far Cry 4's map editor, can you have the player spawn in riding a boat/jetski? Can you have them spawn in a car?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can spawn on boats but beware if you place them in the water you may get an "object below terrain" error in the editor, which really sucks.